# I have a file in AWS s3. what I want is that I need to preview the file in my angular for that I was getting file url using .getSignedUrl in my node

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, amazon-s3

The file S3 URL belongs to pdf file, when I assigned that URL to SRC of  element in my angular, instead of previewing it was downloading the file, even in the params of .getSignedUrl methos I have set 'ResponseContentDisposition: "inline"', still the file gets downloaded. I need help.

I need to preview the file instead of downloading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you didn't specify the correct metadata, you should set the proper MIME media type for your objects in the bucket.
If you want to have the possibility to preview your pdf documents in the browser instead of downloading them, your object in the bucket should have:

```
Content-Type: application/pdf
```

Comment: So do you want me to add ContentType in the object while I am saving the file into S3 in order to get that particular File URL which has to be displayed rather than downloading.
right?

Comment: Correct! If you are using aws sdk to upload an object into an s3 bucket you can specify the ContentType as a parameter

Comment: Great! You're welcome!

Comment: hi Peca021 still need one more help, even If I set content-type it is working for pdf and image files, but MS Word files are still downloading, what to do ?

Comment: Hey @galilohith you should set the proper MIME media type for MS Word files as well, if your files have the .doc extension you should set application/msword as a content-type

Comment: yes i have set that, but it is not working.

Comment: Did you check on the AWS console what is specified as a content type for that object?